# c++ Pass an array instead of a variable length argument list

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-functions

So I have a function that takes a variable length argument list, for example:

```
int avg(int count,...){
    //stuff
}
```

I can call it with `avg(4,2,3,9,4);` and it works fine. It needs to maintain this functionality.

Is there a way for me to also call it with an array instead of listing the variables? For example:

`avg(4,myArray[5])` such that the function `avg` doesn't see any difference?

Comment: No, there isn't. It would be much easier to change the function itself to take an initializer list.

Comment: Function overloading?

Comment: function overloading presents me with the same problem. I still can't have an argument list with a dynamic length at runtime. I realise there are a thousand ways to do this without `...` but I was wondering if I could do it without changing the function.

Comment: Define what you can change. Also this `avg(4,myArray[5]) ` looks strange, please clarify that., it would be best to provide unit test which should pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no such way. You can however make two functions, one that takes a variable number of arguments, and one that takes an array (or better yet, an `std::vector`). The first function simply packs the arguments into the array (or vector) and calls the second function.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought it might be impossible but I wanted to make sure. I was hoping there might be some way to type cast into whatever type a variable length argument list is.

Answer (score 3):

```
void f() {}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void f(T array[N])
{
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void f(const T& value, const Args&... args)
{
    process(value);
    f(args...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Since pointers are essentially unsigned integers it would not be able to tell the difference between a memory address and an unsigned integer. Alternatively (as I am sure you wanted to avoid), you would have to do:

```
avg( 4, myArray[ 0 ], ..., myArray[ 3 ] );
```

... where `...` is `myArray` at positions 1 and 2 **if** you wanted to conform with the same parameters as your previous function. There are other ways to do this, such as using C++ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it

```
struct{int arr[100];}p;

double avg2(int count,int* arr){
    memcpy(&p,arr,count*sizeof(int));
    return avg(count,p);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use of global variable to pass arguments is worst possible approach and this doesn't meet requirement, original `avg` is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be get rid of variadic arguments. This was inherited from `C` and it is a good practice to avoid it as much as possible.

Now your example `avg(4,myArray[5])` is a bit fuzzy. I assume, that first argument defines how much items must be taken from array and second argument you planned to pass just an array. I assume this index operator is typo or limping method showing array size.

So you expect something like this:

```cpp
int avg(int count, ...)
{
    int sum = 0;
    std::va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        sum += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return sum / count;
}

template <size_t N, size_t... I>
int avg_helper(size_t count, const int (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return avg(count, arr[I]...);
}

template <size_t N>
int avg(int count, const int (&arr)[N])
{
    if (count > N)
        throw std::invalid_argument { "to large count passed" };
    return avg_helper(count, arr, std::make_index_sequence<N> {});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7v1n7zaWq

Now note that in overload resolution variadic function is match as a last one. So when  compiler can match template it will select it instead variadic function.

Note there is a trap. If you will pass a pointer (for example array decay) variadic argument function will kick in again. So as protection I've added extra overload which will trigger `static_assert` warning about array decay.